# sql, Внешний ключ

Tags: sql, база-данных

Можно ли делать связь между двумя таблицами двумя внешними ключами ?
Если да , то в чем ошибка ?

```
    create table if not exists first(
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    Surname varchar(40) not null,
    Name varchar(40) not null,
    Patronymic varchar(40),
    Birth datetime not null default current_timestamp,
    phone varchar(20)
);
create table if not exists second(
contact_id int not null auto_increment primary key,
Person_ID int,
phone varchar(20),
mail varchar(30),
address varchar(40),
foreign key(Person_ID) references first(id),
 foreign key(phone) references first(phone)
);
```

что нужно добавить в код , чтобы при появление строчки с человеком в first ,в second автоматически появлялась строчка где указан

Answer (score 0):

> Можно ли делать связь между двумя таблицами двумя внешними ключами ?

Да сколько угодно - FOREIGN KEY независимы.

---

> Если да , то в чем ошибка ?

Поле, на которое ссылается FK (в данном случае это `first(phone)`) должно быть префиксом какого-либо индекса. Об этом явно сообщает и текст ошибки:

> Failed to add the foreign key constraint. **Missing index** for constraint 'second_ibfk_2' in the referenced table 'first'

Для исправления нужно создать такой индекс:

```
CREATE INDEX first_phone ON first (phone);
```

После этого вторая таблица будет создана без проблем: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=62c4a530d370760b3f1aca1494086623

Однако наличие поля `phone` в таблице `second` вообще избыточно - ибо его значение однозначно определяется по `Person_ID`. Следует удалить это поле и соответствующий внешний ключ из структуры таблицы, а при необходимости получать значение в запросе на основании связи.

---

> что нужно добавить в код , чтобы при появление строчки с человеком в first ,в second автоматически появлялась строчка где указан

Триггер `AFTER INSERT`. Но лучше делать такие операции явно - либо выполнять запись в первую таблицу и реферальную запись во вторую в хранимой процедуре, либо клиентским кодом. Основной резон в том, что, кроме собственно `Person_ID`, никакой другой информации нет - зачем создавать фактически пустую запись?